# How ExpiresByType and Header set Cache-Control works together?

Tags: htaccess, cache, cache-control, mod-headers

I have:

```
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 2 years"
```

And let's say:

```
<filesMatch ".(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public"
</filesMatch>
```

When will jpg files expire ? In 2 years or in one year (31536000 seconds) ?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 2 years"
> ```

First... to clarify, this should probably be `image/jpeg`, not `image/jpg`. `image/jpeg` is the official mime-type for JPEG files. Check the `Content-Type` HTTP response header associated with this response. For instance, if your server is sending JPEG files with a `image/jpeg` mime-type (as it should be), then the above directive is not doing anything.

Note that `image/jpg` has nothing to do with the file extension (eg. `.jpg`) that might be on the underlying filename. It refers to the mime-type the server is sending the resource as.

So, for the remainder of my answer, I assume this is the correct mime-type that your server is sending.

> When will jpg files expire ? In 2 years or in one year (31536000 seconds) ?

The answer to this does depend on the type of request/response and what you are doing server-side. ie. Does the request map directly to a physical file or not? Since you mention "jpg files" then #1 below probably applies here (the most common scenario) and the "jpg file" will expire in 1 year.

#### 1. Request maps directly to a physical `.jpg` file

The request maps directly to a physical JPEG file on disk (either directly or via an internal rewrite<sup>***1**</sup>). eg. `/myimage.jpg` - which would indeed be the most common use case (ie. you are linking directly to your static resources) then the JPEG file will expire in 1 year, by the `Header` directive. This is because:

1. `<FilesMatch>` (and `<Files>`) containers only match physical files.
2. The `Header` directive is processed later and so will always override the `Cache-Control` header that mod_expires might otherwise set.

<sup>***1**</sup> Note that you could link to (ie. *request*) `/get-image.php`, but providing the request is internally rewritten directly to an underlying `.jpg` file on disk, eg. `/some-image.jpg` then the same applies.

#### 2. Request does NOT map directly to a physical file

HOWEVER, if the request does not map to a physical file. For example, if either of the following scenarios is true (both are really the same):

- You are linking to a PHP script that serves the JPEG image (either by creating it, or reading it from a different location, etc.) and there is no internal rewrite to a physical file.

  ```
  href="send-image.php?name=myimage.jpg&size=medium"
  ```
- You are linking to a `.jpg` URL, eg. `href="/myotherimage-medium.jpg"` and you are internally rewriting this to a script (like above) that generates this image and returns it to the client.

Then the JPEG image will expire in 2 years since the `<FilesMatch>` directive will not apply, because the request does not map directly to a physical file.

Note that in both cases (scenario **#1** and **#2** above), the `ExpiresByType` directive will apply, but the `Header` directive will always override this if it is applied.

Actually, there is a further complication here... mod_expires sets 2 response headers `Cache-Control: max-age` *and* `Expires`. `Expires` is only for old browsers, all modern browsers prioritise the `Cache-Control: max-age` header. So, in case #1 above, where the request maps directly to a physical file then you'll have a conflict of headers... `Cache-Control: max-age` will state that it expires in 1 year (overridden by the `Header` directive), whereas the `Expires` header will state that it expires in 2 years (set my mod_expires).

So, unless you have specific caching requirements<sup>***2**</sup> then use mod_expires only.

<sup>***2**</sup> mod_expires only sets the `max-age` directive on the `Cache-Control` header. If you need to set other directives, eg. `no-store` or `must-revalidate` etc. then you will need to use the `Header` directive instead (or as well as).

Reference:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile I found a subject on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5799906/what-s-the-difference-between-expires-and-cache-control-headers

There, one user also gives a link to w3: https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html which says:

> If a response includes both an Expires header and a max-age directive, the max-age directive overrides the Expires header, even if the Expires header is more restrictive. This rule allows an origin server to provide, for a given response, a longer expiration time to an HTTP/1.1 (or later) cache than to an HTTP/1.0 cache. This might be useful if certain HTTP/1.0 caches improperly calculate ages or expiration times, perhaps due to desynchronized clocks.