# What's the difference between access and access plus in ExpiresByType directive?

Tags: htaccess, apache, cache, cache-control, expires

I have seen:

```
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
```

But also:

```
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
```

So, what's the difference between those two lines ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two directives are the same.

The `plus` keyword is entirely optional. It is just syntactic sugar, to make it (arguably) more "readable".

As stated in the [Apache docs for mod_expires](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_expires.html):

> ```
> ExpiresByType type/encoding "base[plus num type] [num type] ..."
> ```
>
> :
> The `plus` keyword is optional.

So, include it or not - it is up to you. But, as with everything, it is important to be consistent. Include it OR don't include it; don't mix it.

---

*Aside:*

> ```
> ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
> ```

As I noted in [my answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/132865/1243) to [your other question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/132851/how-expiresbytype-and-header-set-cache-control-works-together), you should probably be using `image/jpeg` here, not `image/jpg`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. One thing to say: I read the apache docs before to understand the plus keyword, but it wasn't clear for me "`The plus keyword is optional`". In my opinion `optional` doesn't mean `same effect`. For me it means that using it you will get `this`, not using it you will get `this`. That's why I was confused.

Comment: Yes, it may seem a bit strange that the `plus` keyword is literally just _optional_, as in "throw-away" optional. And not "optional" as in an "optional parameter". This _alternative syntax_ is simply for readability, so the additional adjective just makes it read more naturally. (The "normal" syntax is a bit more cryptic and is "rarely" used, but is more machine friendly, eg. `ExpiresByType image/jpeg A31536000`.)